# What is a/the $K^*$ meson, and why is it important?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, standard-model, mesons

I know that the standard pseudoscalar $K$ mesons are:

1. $K^+$: valence quark content $u\bar s$; electric charge $+1$; spin $0$; parity $-1$;
2. $K^-$: valence quark content $\bar u s$; electric charge $-1$; spin $0$; parity $-1$;
3. $K^0$: valence quark content $d \bar s$; electric charge $0$; spin $0$; parity $-1$;
4. $\bar K^0$: valence quark content $\bar d s$; electric charge $0$; spin $0$; parity $-1$;

   - (I also know about $K^0_S$ and $K^0_L$)

However I keep seeing the symbol $K^*$ pop up over and over again. Apparently [from the particle data group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/tables/rpp2015-tab-mesons-strange.pdf) (see page 9), it seems $K^*$ is the first excited state of the $K^0$, with excitation energy $892 \,\textrm{MeV}$. But also, it seems like $K^*$ can refer to any excited state of a $K^0$ meson, and so the correct notation would be $K^*(E)$, where $E$ is the excitation energy in $\textrm{MeV}$.

As for the importance of "$K^*$", notice that in [this theoretical paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00718) which calculates the pseudoscalar decay constants, the symbol $K^*$ is quickly and confidently used on page 4. But what does $K^*$ even mean here?

Comment: Note $K^*$ is used for the scalar, the vector, and normal parity tensors. The pseuodscalar, the axial vector, the spin 2 negative parity guys... etc. lacks a *. Absence of * means absence of $\gamma _5$ in the wavefunction.

Comment: @CosmasZachos In your last sentence, did you mean to write "Presence of $^*\,\implies$ absence of $\gamma^5$"? Because $K^0$ has no $^*$, but its wavefunction has a $\gamma^5$ (because it's a pseudoscalar), right? I might have this wrong.

In [this PDG listing](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/ParticleGroup.action?init=0&node=MXXX020), it looks like $^*$ is having a normal orbital angular momentum and parity relationship, i.e. $(-1)^P=(-1)^L$, if that makes sense. Which would mean that in a $K^*$ wavefunction, you don't have any $\gamma^5$.

Comment: You are right, I inverted my double negatives. * means no $\gamma_5$....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$K^*$ on its own is taken as being the $K^*(892)$. Sloppy notation maybe, but it is met with a lot, and has a clean signature whereas the higher excitations are harder to pull out from the data. The nature of the excitation is not radial or angular, just that the quark spins are aligned rather than opposed. (What the atomic physicists would call hyperfine structure which, paradoxically, is larger than fine structure for particle states.) So the four $K^*$ states are spin 1 'vector' particles, and the paper you link to is concerned with those.